# SQlite select returns "(null)" instead of "" for empty values

Tags: mysql, linux, database, sqlite

I have written a C program in Linux that reads a local Sqlite3 DB to update a remote MySQL DB.
When optional fields in the Sqlite table are empty I get the string "(null)" when doing a select. This ends with a lot of "(null)" strings in the remote MySQL database.

Is there any flag or configuration option in Sqlite3 to get empty strings "" when the table's field is empty?

EDITED:

As CL. mentioned it is the snprintf function, when building the sql_query, who creates the "(null)" string for NULL values. That is not what I want so I guess I have to check each value to see if it's NULL or not? Is there a better way? in this example it doesn't matter but in the real one there are a lot of fields..

SAMPLE CODE:
This is the callback function that executes after sqlite select, then I build a sql query with the data obtained to update the remote MySQL:

```
static int callback_sync_Table(void *NotUsed, int argc, char **argv, char **azColName){

int rc;
char *zErrMsg = NULL;
char sql_query[512];

memset(sql_query, '\0', sizeof(sql_query));
snprintf(sql_query, sizeof(sql_query)-1, "INSERT INTO table(field_1,field_2,field_3) VALUES("
         "\"%s\",\"%s\",\"%s\") ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE "
         "field_1=\"%s\",field_2=\"%s\",field_3=\"%s\";",
         argv[0], argv[1], argv[2],
         argv[0], argv[1], argv[2],);

if(mysql_query(mysql_db_conn, sql_query)){
    fprintf(stderr, "MySQL error: %s\n", mysql_error(mysql_db_conn));
    syslog(LOG_DEBUG, "MySQL error: %s", mysql_error(mysql_db_conn));
}
return 0;
```

}

Comment: `NULL` and the empty string `''` are not the same thing. If you do not want nulls in the database in the first place, add the `NOT NULL` constraint to your SQLite column, and don't insert them in the first place.

Comment: The database does not generate the string `(null)` for NULL values. However, the `printf()` function does this for NULL pointers. Show your code!

Comment: Yes, you are right, of course it is the snprintf, I am blind! See my edit. Is there a better way than checking each value to see if it is NULL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `snprintf` to compose an SQL query in this way is bad not only because of the nulls, but also because you might run into [all kinds of trouble](https://xkcd.com/327/) due to the fact that you're not escaping your strings.

I'd suggest using the [prepared statements API](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/c-api-prepared-statements.html) instead. When you use that, at the C level you'd have to explicitely set some `is_bool` flag according to whether a given value is `NULL` or not.

Comment: Thanks MvG, I didn't know about prepared statements, they are really useful. I have re-written the code and seems to work perfectly. Now my code is more efficient, secure and professional. Thanks!

Comment: So @japjap, how did you solve the problem? maybe you need to write the solve in the answer section